# Removing file extensions in .htaccess with wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a static website running in conjunction with wordpress in the same dir, it all works fine. However, on the static pages that don't use wordpress I cannot seem to remove the .php file extensions my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index2.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /index.php/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Alternate default index page
DirectoryIndex index2.php

ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/index2.php
```

I have tried adding this code as you usually would but it wont work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php                       [L]
```

Comment: it still takes me to the 404 page

Comment: why do you have this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ?

Comment: Because `/test` is not a file, but `/test.php` would be a file. Your method, however, is correct. It just needs to be placed correctly.

Comment: Exactly, but this is supposed to work on php files as the "*..remove the `.php` file extensions..*" in the OP, so I don't understand why checking if not file **`!-f`**, and indeed this has been working for me since years

Comment: @MikeRockett So where would I place the code to make it work?

Comment: It should be done before rewriting to WordPress. So, put it under `RewriteEngine on`.